# Brightcove video.js doesn't supported VAST tag

Tags: video.js, brightcove, video-player

Brightcove 2013 video.js doesn't supported VAST tag. Its only supported 2011 Zencoder video.js. How to run Brightcove video.js with VAST tag. anyone know this, please help me.

Comment: I wasn't aware the old video.js supported the VAST tag. What did it look like to use VAST with the old version?

Comment: when i using old version of video.js with VAST while the video player controls alignment has been changed. Mouseover/Mouseout events also not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I've bookmarked this on my computer for the future, but haven't been tracking it.

Theonion.com has put this on github.  I'm not sure of how complete it is, or if it works but its a start.

https://github.com/theonion/videojs-vast-plugin